# JsonSchema and validation

Tags: java, json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

colleagues! I am trying use jsonSchema for validation of input object (Json as string). But I have an issue with the next message: **com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No suitable validator for id** .

My Schema like this:

````
    ```
{
      "type" : "object",
      "id" : "urn:jsonschema:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:Class_name",
      "properties" : {
    ///objects 
      }
    }
```
````

and code with trying to validate:

```
JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(VersionFlag.V201909);
        InputStream stream=TestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.json");
        JsonSchema schema=factory.getSchema(stream);
        JsonNode node =mapper.convertToJsonNode(MyObject.builder().build());
        Set<ValidationMessage> validationResult = schema.validate(node);
```

My goal: if the fields are entered incorrectly, output a list of all these fields to the response. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and are there other options for validation all json keys (not values)?

Current library:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.63</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have no experience with JSON-schema, but a quick scan of the JSON meta-schema spec seems to reveal that there is no `"id":` validation keyword.  That looks misplaced to me, does it belong inside `"properties": ( ... )`?

Comment: Hello,Jim! No, it's about the very first id ("id" : "urn:jsonschema:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x:Class_name") . I have deleted it now and the error does not occur

Answer (score 0):

Jim's on the right track.

For draft 2019-09 (which you seen to be using, `JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(VersionFlag.V201909)`), `id` should be `$id`.

This change was made as of draft 6 (two versions previous).